# How to fix "Priority Queue Remove function not working "

Tags: java, object, queue, priority-queue

I am using Priority Queue in one of my java code (Pair Class). I encountered one minor issue that uses remove function (PQ) which is not giving  results. After a while ,I detect my mistake but I don't know the reason behind this issue . Can anyone explain me the logical reason behind this issue(Why last line of my code giving me false)??

I am new to this platform ,Before posting this Question I searched a lot over internet, but not getting suitable reason which would justify the above problem.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class PQ_IMP {

  static class Pair{
    int a ;
    int b;
    int c;
    Pair(int x,int y,int z){
        a=x;b=y;c=z;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    PriorityQueue<Pair> name =new PriorityQueue<Pair>(new Comparator<Pair>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair o1, Pair o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.a,o2.a);
        }
    });

    Pair n=new Pair(1,2,3);
    name.add(n);
    System.out.println(name.remove(n));  // Print true

    name.add(n);
    n=new Pair(1,2,3);
    System.out.println(name.remove(n));  // Print False
  }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to remove a Pair object that isn't equal (in terms of Object.equals()) to any Pair in the queue. So removing it doesn't have any effect. So the method returns false.

Comment: You may wish to consider implementing `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` on your `Pair` object.